# Showing modal Popup on ajax success in Laravel

Tags: html, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-8

`here, I need to show the image details on image_upload table, while click show button
click this button id passed

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="" onclick="showuserimage({{$user->id}})">Show</a>

function showuserimage(id)
{
   $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
       
        url: 'imageshow/{id}',
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(data){
       $("#getCode").html(data);
       $("#getCodeModal").modal("show");
       }
   });
}
Route::post('imageshow/{id}',[AuthController::class,'showimage']);

public function showimage(Request $request)
      {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
     
        $image= ImageUpload::whereId($id)->get();
       
        $result_data=array();
        foreach($image as $img)
        {
         // print_r($img['name']);
          $result_data['id']=$img['id'];
          $result_data['name']=$img['name'];
          $result_data['image_id']=$img['image_id'];
          $result_data['user_id']=$img['user_id'];
        
        }
        return $result_data;
 }
```

get error on the console,
uncaught
XHR finished loading: POST
expecting showing popup`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of mistakes here:

1. The way you pass the `id`. Currently you're passing it both via the URL and and via request data. Kindly choose one.
2. The URL AJAX is wrong. You're passing the literal `{id}` instead of the variable `id` itself. Also `'imageshow/{id}'` is invalid if you're not on the homepage put slash at the front. So the proper URL is `url: '/imageshow/' + id,`.
3. The controller function is expecting an `id` parameter.

So this is one solution to your answer:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="" onclick="showuserimage({{$user->id}})">Show</a>
```

```
function showuserimage(id)
{
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/imageshow/' + id,
        success:function(data){
            $("#getCode").html(data);
            $("#getCodeModal").modal("show");
        }
    });
}
```

```
Route::post('imageshow/{id}',[AuthController::class,'showimage']);
```

```
public function showimage(Request $request, $id)
{
    $image= ImageUpload::whereId($id)->get();

    $result_data=array();
    foreach($image as $img) {
        // print_r($img['name']);
        $result_data['id']=$img['id'];
        $result_data['name']=$img['name'];
        $result_data['image_id']=$img['image_id'];
        $result_data['user_id']=$img['user_id'];
    }
    return $result_data;
}
```

I really suggest that you learn the basics of PHP, Javascript, AJAX and Laravel and basic debugging techniques.